# How do I make Quartz.NET run jobs from separate assembly?

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am new to Quartz.NET so bear with me please.
I would like to run Quartz.NET as a stand-alone service which runs jobs.
I would like to create a different assembly containing all the jobs I need to run and have Quartz **configured** to run these jobs from my assembly.

Thus, whenever I create a new job, I add this to my assembly and all I am left to do is to replace the old assembly and restart the Quartz service.

Is this possible?

Could anyone please show/redirect me to a code example showing how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to seek a good solution for your question, first of all as Quartz.examples has in the example12 and 13, you can create via Remoting.net a stand-alone server, and it's very simple the way to do that just make yourself a copy-paste ;-). Besides you have to add a reference of your assembly of jobs into the server's assembly in order to stablish a communication of whom Wich "Execute() method" have to exe and for be avoid of exceptions... then you could create a Clientremoting where you just have to select the job that you would schedule and run it using the same port, channel and binding than the server. Let me know if you wanna some example codes of it.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your answer. However, I am not familiar with Remoting.NET.
Anyhow, I was planning to do what you said: creating an assembly of jobs implementing the IJob interface. But I don't know how to wire it up to the Quartz. I will love to have some example codes.

Comment: Just a remark: you don't need to add a reference to the jobs assembly into the server's assembly, you only need to "drop" (copy/paste) the jobs assembly in the same folder than the server's assembly. As long as the jobs assembly is in the probing path, it will be OK, as quartz.net is using reflection to load a given Job type.