# Executing a Quartz.NET job from a separate assembly

Tags: assemblies, quartz.net

I'm trying to execute a Quartz.net job from a separate assembly.  The class inherits from the IJob interface, implements the Execute method, and has been copied into the same folder as Quartz.Server.exe, but I'm getting the following error:

`Error scheduling jobs: Could not load file or
 assembly 'TestJobs' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a p
rogram with an incorrect format.
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestJobs' or on
e of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'TestJobs'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError,
Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Bool
ean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   ... (snipped)`

I'm using [version 2 beta 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quartznet/files/quartznet/Quartz.NET%202.0%20beta%202/).  The server application has been unzipped into a separate folder and is being executed by running Quartz.Server.exe at the command line.

My sample job is a separate assembly named TestsJobs with a very basic job to write to a text file:

```
public class TestJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"c:\test.txt";
            while (true)
            {
                var line = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + Guid.NewGuid();
                File.AppendAllText(path, line);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new JobExecutionException("Error", ex, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a basic class library project targeting .NET 4.  It is copied into the Quartz.Net server folder where Quartz.Server.exe is being run from.

The quartz_jobs.xml file has the job set using the default file, with just the job type changed to reflect the new assembly and class:

```
<job-type>TestJobs.TestJob, TestJobs</job-type>
```

Thought this might be something to do with framework versioning, but Quartz.net seems to be using .NET 4 as well (Quartz.dll has dependencies on v4 assemblies).

There's [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753965/how-do-i-make-quartz-net-run-jobs-from-separate-assembly) about the same type of issue, but it doesn't have a clear answer.

Is there anything else I need to do so that the job can be loaded and executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be a bit simpler that I thought.  It was caused by my assembly with the test job being compiled for x86 instead of AnyCPU (or x64) and using Windows 7 x64.